# Why doesn't copying large files prevent Linux from going into power saving mode?

Tags: linux, power-management

This problem [happened to me when copying backups from an SSD to an external SSD](https://askubuntu.com/q/652643/25388). As suggested in the answer there, I had to change my power settings to set "suspend when inactive" to "never" in Debian 8.1, while in OSX I can keep it set at 15 minutes and nightly backups still work fine. OSX seems to consider copying as an active state, while Linux does not.

Why does Linux consider copying inactive state?

Comment: @richard They linked right to that question in this one, and this looks like a follow-up, not the same question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my memory serves me right, activity detection depends upon user input (nodes under `/dev/input/`). If these nodes are silent for a given amount of time, then the state is assumed inactive.

If copying under OSX appears as though it prevents the system from dozing then the command itself must be written (i.e. coded) as such (to prevent the system from going idle) for I don't clearly see how it could be based on disk activity; in most circumstances the disk is *always* active, be it for logging purposes. But I'm no kernel developer, just thinking aloud.